# Accessing Context Inside of TabNavigator? React Native

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I currently have a tab navigator nested inside a stack navigator.

I've been trying to adjust my tabnavigator so it's able to leverage the `useContext()` hook to conditionally display a tab but haven't had any luck.

Here's my `navigation.js` file:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    ...(myInfo
      ? {
          MyInfo: {
            screen: MyInfo,
            navigationOptions: {
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                let source;
                focused
                  ? (source = require('../assets/MyInfo_Inactive.png'))
                  : (source = require('../assets/MyInfo_Inactive.png'));
                return <Image style={{ marginTop: 30 }} source={source} />;
              },
            },
          },
        }
      : {}),
    Account: {
      screen: Account,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          let source;
          focused
            ? (source = require('../assets/Account_Inactive.png'))
            : (source = require('../assets/Account_Inactive.png'));
          return <Image style={{ marginTop: 30 }} source={source} />;
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      tabBarOptions: {
        showLabel: false,
      },
    },
  },
);

const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: {
      screen: TabNavigator,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);

export default MainStackNavigator;
```

Where 'myInfo' would come from my context.

and my `App.js` file:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStackNavigator);

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <AccountProvider>
        <AppContainer />
    </AccountProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any help is super appreciated as I'm new to React Native and have been trying to find an answer that works for quite some time.

Thanks!

Comment: did you get this solution

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 no I didn't, what I ended up making two separate navigators and conditionally choosing one after a user logged in and the context was set